# Case Assignment Email for Live Chat case cannot see linked Account, Contact

Tags: case, service-cloud-console, servicecloud, pre-chat-api

I have a Live Chat implementation that links an Account and a Contact to the new case using `embedded_svc.settings.extraPrechatInfo`; the external site where the chat is hosted passes a unique external id for each.  This works fine, and when a new chat pops in Service Console, the account and contact are already linked.

However, the Case Assignment email (Setup > Feature Settings > Support Settings > Case Assigned Template) shows Blank (null) for `{!Case.AccountId}` and `{Case.ContactId}`.  This seems wrong; I thought the prechat info, including Account and Contact links, should be populated on insert?

I'm considering disabling the OOB Case Assignment email, and just sending the email via flow on Case creation, since the Case only appears to be created once an agent accepts the case.  Is that my only option?